# Is it possible to make a thread-safe queue with simultaneous push and pop?

Tags: c, multithreading

This is more of a theoretical rather than useful question, but I cannot think of a way to do this. To be clear, the goal is to make a queue which allows multiple threads to both push and pop simultaneously without blocking each other.

An example of the goal is:
Thread A pushes twice. Thread A and thread B call `push`, thread C and thread D call `pop`. Thread A gets queue location 2, thread B gets queue location 3, thread C gets queue location 0, and thread D gets queue location 1. All threads are able to read from/write to their respective locations at the same time.

These push and pop functions can do this, but are not thread-safe:

```c
#include <pthreads.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

...

void push(void* item) {
    sem_wait(push_avaliability);
    int slot = atomic_fetch_add(tail, 1) % queue_size;
    pthread_mutex_lock(access_queue[slot]);
    queue[slot] = item;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(access_queue[slot]);
    sem_post(pop_avaliability);
}

void* pop() {
    sem_wait(pop_avaliability);
    int slot = atomic_fetch_add(head, 1) % queue_size;
    pthread_mutex_lock(access_queue[slot]);
    void* item = queue[slot];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(access_queue[slot]);
    sem_post(push_avaliability);
}
```

`head` and `tail` are both initialized to 0, `push_avaliability` is initialized to the size of the queue, and `pop_avaliability` is initialized to 0. These are the only two functions that modify these variables. (I know that there is an overflow potential with head/tail and that storing pointers in the array makes the thread-safety of the queue unimportant, but those problems are not important for this question.)

An example of the problem is:
Suppose that thread A and thread B call `push` and thread C calls `pop`. Thread A gets slot 0 but does not lock it, then thread B gets slot 1 and writes to it and posts that there is a space written to. Thread C wakes and gets slot 0, and attempts to read from it, but thread A has not written to it yet.

I could fix this problem by incrementing head/tail and writing/reading inside a mutex that prevented access to the whole queue by any other thread, but I want to know if it is possible to do this in a way that allows multiple threads to be writing to and reading from the queue at the same time.

Comment: AFAIK, not safely.  A reliable, efficient multiple producer-consumer queue requires a mutes and either a semaphore or condvar, (more if bounded).

Comment: You should take a look at lock-free queues - the simplest and best known (though not the best performing) is the [Michael Scott queue](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I am using:

```c
void push(void* item) {
    sem_wait(push_avaliability);
    int slot = atomic_fetch_add(tail, 1) % queue_size;
    while(slot_full[slot] != false);
    queue[slot] = item;
    slot_full[slot] = true;
    sem_post(pop_avaliability);
}

void* pop() {
    sem_wait(pop_avaliability);
    int slot = atomic_fetch_add(head, 1) % queue_size;
    while(slot_full[slot] != true);
    void* item = queue[slot];
    slot_full[slot] = false;
    sem_post(push_avaliability);
    return item;
}
```

(`slot_full[i]` is initialized to false)

The while loop does not use a significant amount of time because the semaphores mostly handle waiting for the slot to open. (In testing, the while loop condition was never true.) If the copy operation was expensive, then using a condition variable would be the way to go, but I think that would probably be more expensive on average than this solution.

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.8674&rep=rep1&type=pdf) was a useful reference for lock-free queues, along with mpoeter's comment.